# Transform data stream using processor implemented via Flow APIs

Tags: java, concurrency, java-8, java-9, data-stream

I was going through the [Community#DOC-1006738](https://community.oracle.com/docs/DOC-1006738) from Oracle related to the concurrency concepts of `Flow.Publisher` and `Flow.Subscriber`. There on one can find the *Sample code to transform data stream using processor* which has these two lines of code, which has left me a little puzzled.

```
//Create Processor and Subscriber  
MyFilterProcessor<String, String> filterProcessor = 
                                      new MyFilterProcessor<>(s -> s.equals("x"));
```

**Question 1. How could the MyFilterProcessor be of type `<String, String>` here?**

To what I at first thought was, these might have been `<String, Boolean>` instead, but then that would defy the further definition of the subscriber definition in the next line :-

```
MyTransformProcessor<String, Integer> transformProcessor = 
                              new MyTransformProcessor<>(s -> Integer.parseInt(s));
```

*Additional note* here, unless I explicitly cast(correct) the above as

```
MyTransformProcessor<String, Integer>(s -> Integer.parseInt(s))
```

I get an error in ***`parseInt`*** reading, ***cannot be applied to `Object`***.

<sub>-- **Why do I need to explicitly cast the RHS here?** --</sub>

---

Though the code is mostly present in the shared link, yet the useful constructor definitions I am using are

```
public class MyTransformProcessor<T, R> extends SubmissionPublisher<R> implements Flow.Processor<T, R> {       
    private Function function;
    MyTransformProcessor(Function<? super T, ? extends R> function) {  
        super();  
        this.function = function;  
    } 
    ...
}
```

and an identical one for `filterProcessor` as :-

```
public class MyFilterProcessor<T, R> extends SubmissionPublisher<R> implements Flow.Processor<T, R> {
    private Function function;
    MyFilterProcessor(Function<? super T, ? extends R> function) {
        super();
        this.function = function;
    }
    ...
}
```

**Question. Now with those changes(*one after resolving the question 1 and another from the additional note*), how can one implement the sample correctly? Or am I simply missing out on something very basic?**

Comment: Sample/reproducible code is in the the [following package on github](https://github.com/namannigam/jdk-concurrency/tree/master/src/main/java/concurrency/oracle). Info - tagging with Java-8 for `Function` implementation and Java-9 for the usage of `Flow` APIs in the context.

Comment: Any reasons for downvoting are more than welcome :)

Comment: I didn't down vote, but I'm wondering why are you using `Flow` API in the 'manner' of single Thread? Maybe for better understanding? I suggest to read carefully JDK-9 API docs... (Rally, I'm too lazy to do this). Good luck, friend.

Comment: I didn't down vote either, but your post seems to be about nothing more than an error in a blog, and I share your confusion. However, this was an article on the JDK 9 Flow API published a year before Java 9 was released, and the author of the article didn't even provide the source code for MyFilterProcessor. Perhaps I am misunderstanding your concern, but is it really worth worrying about? Why not just pick a more recent tutorial that works?

Comment: @MarkoPacak The GitHub code should be pretty clear now. Have made sure that only relevant classes are there and nomenclature is same as the question in the package shared. The class to look at is `TransformDataStreamUsingProcessor.java`

Answer (score 3):

I believe your major mistake was implementing `MyFilterProcessor` as an (almost) exact copy of `MyTransformProcessor`.

Since the author did not post the code of the said class, I tried to guess its behavior based on:

```
... = new MyFilterProcessor<>(s -> s.equals("x"));
```

The name `Filter` suggests the component is meant to accept and then re-publish only certain values. At this point a function that evaluates to a `boolean` (or a `Predicate<T>`) is quite acceptable within the context ( and thus `s -> s.equals("x")` ).

The initial data stream at the end of the page

```
String[] items = {"1", "x", "2", "x", "3", "x"};
```

seems to confirm my assumptions. The author simply wants to filter out the `"x"` values, and this task is given to `MyFilterProcessor` which must evaluate each type before posting it to the rest of the pipeline; and the output type must be the same as the input type.

---

The constructor should then look like this:

```
MyFilterProcessor(Predicate<? super R> predicate) { /* ... */ }
// or
MyFilterProcessor(Function<? super R, Boolean> function) { /* ... */ }
```

and `onNext` supposedly forwards only certain elements:

```
if (! predicate.test(item)) {
    int max = submit(item); // get the estimated maximum lag
    subscription.request(max);
}
```

I have a two ideas for the definition of `MyFilterProcessor`:

- 1) `public class MyFilterProcessor<T, R> extends SubmissionPublisher<R> implements Flow.Processor<R, R>`

as `Flow.Processor` is meant to accept and forward the same type.

I just can't seem to fit the type `T` anywhere. And this is where I am blocked.

- 2) `public class MyFilterProcessor<T, R> extends SubmissionPublisher<R> implements Flow.Processor<T, R>`

but then, in `onNext`, you must cast `<T>` to `<R>` *(ugly, very ugly)*

```
if (! predicate.test(item)) {
    int max = submit( (R) item);
    subscription.request(max);
}
```

You'd be testing a `Predicate<? super T>` in this case.

If you are willing to refactor a little bit, as `SubmissionPublisher` already inherits the behavior of `Flow.Publisher` you could have the class just implement `Flow.Subscriber`:

```
public class MyFilterProcessor<R> extends SubmissionPublisher<R> implements Flow.Subscriber<R>
```

and so

```
MyFilterProcessor<String, String> filterProcessor = new MyFilterProcessor<>(s -> s.equals("x"));
// or, if you follow my example:
MyFilterProcessor<String> filterProcessor = new MyFilterProcessor<>(s -> s.equals("x"));
```

finally works.

---

If you print the values within `MyFilterProcessor` and `MySubscriber` you will get this output:

```
Publishing Items...
FilterProcessor: Receiving: 1
FilterProcessor: Receiving: x
FilterProcessor: Receiving: 2
FilterProcessor: Receiving: x
FilterProcessor: Receiving: 3
FilterProcessor: Receiving: x
Got: 1
Got: 2
Got: 3
```

which is the expected result.

---

When you test, remember to wait for the pipeline to finish before quitting the application as `SubmissionPublisher` issues the elements in another `Thread`.

Also, please, contrary to article, have the common sense to change

```
private Function function; 
// ...
submit((R) function.apply(item));
```

to

```
private Function<? super T, ? extends R> function;
// ...
submit(function.apply(item));
```

---

> Why do I need to explicitly cast the RHS here?

I'm still struggling to understand how you got the `cannot be applied to Object` error. Which [jdk](/questions/tagged/jdk) number and IDE are you using?

Comment: @nullpointer whats I'm interested in your point of view. Is it the answer you were looking for?